# How nestjs configures path aliases in a project

Tags: nestjs

I configured the path alias in tsconfig.json of the nestjs project, but there was an error while running.

I tried to configure like Angular, but there was an error in nestjs

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "~auth/*": ["src/auth/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Use it like this

```
import { userLoginJwt } from '~auth/jwt-names'
```

Startup error

```
$ npm run start:dev
[0] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
[0]     throw err;
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] Error: Cannot find module 'src/auth/jwt-names'
```

Sorry, I emphasize here that running `npm run start` works fine, but running `npm run start:dev` can lead to unexpected situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This job, I work：

1. Modify my 'tsconfig.json'

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "~auth/*": ["auth/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

2. Add 'tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js' file

```js
// tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js

const tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const tsConfigPaths = require('tsconfig-paths');

tsConfigPaths.register({
  baseUrl: tsConfig.compilerOptions.outDir,
  paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
});
```

3. Modify the 'nodemon.json' file

```
{
  "watch": ["dist"],
  "ext": "js",
  "exec": "node  -r ./tsconfig-paths-bootstrap.js dist/main.js"
}
```

4. Use path alias

```
import { userLoginJwt } from '~auth/jwt-names';
```

Now executing the `npm run start:dev` error has disappeared.

Comment: Nestjs has updated the template and the above code will not work for the new version. For the new version, set the `paths` field directly in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR;**

1. Update your `package.json`

`"start:dev": "nest start --watch --exec 'node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/main.ts'"`

2. Use `npm run start:dev`

Answer (score 3):

`src` is not an available folder after compilation, as all the code is moved to the `dist` folder. Rather, what you should do in your `tsconfig` is set up a `baseUrl` to point to `src` and the `outDir` to point to `dist` then remove `src` from your paths. I'd also suggest reading up on Typescript path mapping to get a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: That's good general advice but NestJS seems to force you to use "./" for baseURL so this is not an option

Answer (score 3):

Only needs:

```json
"moduleResolution": "node",
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "@lib/*": ["lib/*"],
  "@models/*": ["models/*"],
  "@plugins/*": ["plugins/*"],
  "@routes/*": ["routes/*"],
  "@services/*": ["services/*"],
  "@api": ["api/index"]
}
```

https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/how-to-use-module-path-aliases-in-visual-studio-typescript-and-javascript-e7851df8eeaa

Comment: This is the best answer because it scales to any project and there is a good and clear medium post 
I recommend reading also https://alexjover.com/blog/enhance-jest-configuration-with-module-aliases/ in order to add aliases to your Jest settings as well. In Jest it can be done in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

> How nestjs configures path aliases in a project

It doesn't you are showing us the tsconfig file - its TS that is declaring the paths

```
"paths": {
  "~auth/*": ["src/auth/*"]
}
```

would be better if it followed what appears to be a convention of adding @ instead of tilda or even don't use a prefix (as [that is what the docs do](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths))

```
"paths": {
  "@auth/*": ["src/auth/*"]
}
```

Or just all

```
  "paths": {
    "*": [
       "./*"
     ]
   },
```

So thats the path reference sorted... now onto [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) for using short paths after compilation. So the above will be good for the TS, but after its been transpiled to JS the paths are no longer referenced as its JS now... which is why it fails with the start command.

You will need to create a bootstrap script like shown in the docs and calling that in your package.json just before the build command.

Comment: I would argue that tilda is better, now a lot of npm modules are using @ as well, it's easy to get confused if it's a local file or from npm

Comment: Everyone has a different preference, the docs say no prefix, so i would in retrospect go with what the docs say. https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths however @ is the convention i have seen / been working with for a while.